# Navigation Gizmo missing

Tags: interface, navigation

I’ve just downloaded the latest build of Blender 2.81; everything works great, but I noticed the Navigation Gizmo (viewport’s top-right) is currently missing; I found that widget particularly useful when working on the laptop, but now it’s nowhere to be found.

Firstly I thought it’d be a toggle within the overlays drop-down, but I was wrong: only the transform gizmos can be found there.

Has the feature been removed?

Comment: It's not missing for me. Maybe try File -> Defaults -> Load Factory Settings or enable it in the Blender Preferences(F4 -> p), Viewport section, under Display it's called 3D Viewport Axis.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about experimental unreleased version.

Comment: Yes, this question can be closed as resolved. Thank you Martin Z

Comment: I voted to close it because I don't think it is very useful for the community. Experimental builds may have issues because they are being worked on so those issues may be very short lived. They may be fixed in days. I am glad if the issue is resolved, resolved or answered questions should stay here on Blender Stack Exchange for other people having similar questions to find. I just doubted if this is useful in that context, because 2.81 at the moment is an experimental build that's why the vote.